# How to figure out the time difference for events that happen simultaneously in one reference frame?

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

Suppose there's a clock on a spaceship and a clock on earth. The spaceship is moving toward earth at a constant relativistic velocity, and both clocks start simultaneously from the reference frame of earth. The spaceship passes the earth after a certain time. From the reference frame of the ship, how long ago did the earth clock start?

Example:

1. The ship traveling at a speed so that  is 1/2
2. From the point of view of earth, 10 years elapse on earth, and  5 years elapsed on the spaceship, so the earth clock is 5 years ahead of the space one.
3. From the point of view of the spaceship clock, 5 years elapse on the spaceship, and 2.5 years elapsed (since the space clock started) on earth. For the earth clock to be 5 years ahead, it would have had to start 7.5 years before the space clock from the space clocks point of view.

Are there equations that can show where this 7.5 comes from? Or am I completely wrong (a very real possibility since this is all very new to me) and there's something else going on.

Comment: Have you heard of the Lorentz transformation?

Comment: I haven't, could you explain it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/relcon.html#relcon